# Why does RGB use 6 hex digits?

Tags: css, colors, rgb, information-theory

I understand that RGB encodes a color with two hex digits corresponding to the Red, Green, and Blue components. For instance, #ff0000 is pure red. And I understand that each hex digit represents a number from 0-15, or 4-bits of information. But how is it possible to represent every color with 32-bits? Why use two digits for Red and Green and Blue? Why aren't there, for instance, three digits per color?

Comment: *how is it possible to represent every color with 32-bits?* --> what is "every color" for you?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think he means to increase/decrease the accuracy of the encoding

Comment: The number of colors that can be represented by this method are 16,777,216 colors. You also got understand that this was created back in 1996 to work with CRT displays.

Comment: You're misinformed. Up to now, with the exception of very high-end devices, most devices display 24bit colors: total 16,777,216 which is calculated by decimal 256*256*256, or hexadecimal FF* FF *FF. Hence three 2byte hex values.

Comment: Why? convenience. It is one convention, and nobody would have complained with other solutions.There were not many colour screen, so colour were not so priority, so using a single integer was better then e.g. a triplet. Unix used to describe 3 permission in one integer (but there with octals), so why not do the same with colours (HTML is born in Unix). Now we have problems, so we are returning to the definition 0.0 to 1.0 (and also out of this range, because colours are complex), also because we have many 30bit screens

Answer (score 0):

I dont really know if any of this is related to hardware and whether we can even make colors to such detail but a third hex digit for colors means we will have colors with 4096 times more detail, (meaning if we have X color combinations currently, then we will have 4096 * X colors) which we simply dont need, since human eye wont be able to notice the difference, even in our current color system, let alone one much bigger.

So you'd be sacrificing efficiency for nothing in that case, like watching a movie on 600 frames per second while your eye can only process 60.